# How to formulate a connection between pre-execution and post-execution state of a method?

Tags: verification, dafny

I have the following zaMap (see full code here: http://rise4fun.com/Dafny/LCaM):

```
class zaMap {
  var busybits :array<bool>;
  var keys : array<int>;
  var values : array<int>;

  predicate wellformed ()
    reads busybits, keys, values, this
  {
    busybits != null && keys != null && values != null &&
    keys != values &&
    busybits.Length == keys.Length &&
    keys.Length == values.Length
  }

  // ... more predicates and methods follow


  method put(k : int, v : int) returns (success : bool)
    requires wellformed()
    modifies busybits, keys, values
    ensures !success ==> full()
    ensures success ==> mapsto(k, v)
  {
    var i := findEmpty();
    if (i < 0)
    {
      success := false;
      return;
    }
    assert !busybits[i];
    busybits[i] := true;
    keys[i] := k;
    values[i] := v;
    success := true;
  }
//...
```

Now I want to add more specifications to the `put` method. For example, I want to `ensure`, that if the return value is `success == true`, then a map was `!full()` before the function call, or equivalently if a map not `full()`, it is guaranteed to `put` there.

The problem is that, in the precondition "requires" I don't know yet what it will return, and in the postcondition "ensures" I don't have an original map anymore. What people do about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `old` keyword. Let's take a look at an example. The following method sets to zero all positions of an array containing the element `x` and leaving the rest as they are. Here's the code:

```
method setToZero(a: array<int>, x : int )
requires a != null;
modifies a;
ensures forall i :: 0 <= i < a.Length && old(a[i]) == x ==> a[i] == 0;
ensures forall i :: 0 <= i < a.Length && old(a[i]) != x ==> a[i] == old(a[i]);
{
  var j := 0;
  while (j < a.Length)
  invariant 0 <= j <= a.Length;
  invariant forall i :: 0 <= i < j && old(a[i]) == x ==> a[i] == 0;
  invariant forall i :: 0 <= i < j && old(a[i]) != x ==> a[i] == old(a[i]);
  invariant forall i :: j <= i < a.Length ==> a[i] == old(a[i]);
   {
    if (a[j] == x) {
      a[j] := 0;
    }
    j := j + 1;
  }
}
```